# Not getting output when parsing with lxml using xpath in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

When I was trying to scrape the data from Sephora and Ulta using beautifulsoup, I could get the html content of the page. Then when I tried to use lxml to parse it using xpath, i didn't get any output. But working with this same xpath in selenium, i could get the output.

**Using Beautifulsoup**

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    response = requests.get(df['product_url'].iloc[i])
    my_url=df['product_url'].iloc[i]
    My_url= ureq(my_url)
    my_html=My_url.read()
    My_url.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html, 'html.parser')
    dom = et.HTML(str(soup))
#price
    try:
      price=(dom.xpath('//*[@id="1b7a3ab3-2765-4ee2-8367-c8a0e7230fa4"]/span/text()'))
      df['price'].iloc[i]=price
    except:
      pass
```

**Using Selenium**

```
lst=[]
urls=df['product_url']
for url in urls[:599]:
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
         prize=driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="1b7a3ab3-2765-4ee2-8367-c8a0e7230fa4"]/span').text
    except:
        pass
 
    lst.append([prize])
    pz=None
    dt=None
```

Does anyone know why i cant get the content using lxml to parse it using same xpath in beautifulsoup? Thanks so much in advance.

Sample Link of Ulta:
[1]: https://www.ulta.com/p/coco-mademoiselle-eau-de-parfum-spray-pimprod2015831

Sample Link of Sephora:
[2]: https://www.sephora.com/product/coco-mademoiselle-P12495?skuId=513168&icid2=products

Comment: You didn't include the url from which you're fetching the data, but it's highly likely that the web page you're scraping is populated dynamically using Javascript. Selenium works because selenium is a full browser with a javascript engine. Python `requests` is just an http client and will not be able to access dynamic content.

Comment: what are `et` and `ureq`? are you parsing multiple times? I feel like `str(soup)` and `my_html` might be effectively the same thing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### 1. About the XPath

> ```py
> driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="1b7a3ab3-2765-4ee2-8367-c8a0e7230fa4"]/span').text
> ```

I'm a bit surprised that the selenium code works for your Sephora links - the [link](https://www.sephora.com/product/coco-mademoiselle-P12495?skuId=513168&icid2=products) you provided redirects to a [*productnotcarried*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNBvj.png) page, but at [this link](https://www.sephora.com/ca/en/product/fenty-eau-de-parfum-P503757) (for example), that XPath [has no matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz6dC.png). You can use `//p[@data-comp="Price "]//span/b` instead.
[image: seph]

Actually, even for Ulta, I prefer `//*[@class="ProductHero__content"]//*[@class="ProductPricing"]/span` just for human-readability although it looks better if you use this path with [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

```py
prize=driver.find_element("css selector", '*.ProductHero__content *.ProductPricing>span').text
```

---

###### [Coding for both sites - Selenium]

To account for both sites, you could set up something like this reference dictionary:

```py
xRef = {
    'www.ulta.com': '//*[@id="1b7a3ab3-2765-4ee2-8367-c8a0e7230fa4"]/span',
    'www.sephora.com': '//p[@data-comp="Price "]//span/b'
}

# for url in urls[:599]:... ################ REST OF CODE #############
```

and then use it accordingly

```py
# from urllib.parse import urlsplit

# lst, urls, xRef = ....


# for url in urls[:599]:
    # sleep...driver.get...sleep...
    try:
         uxrKey = urlsplit(url).netloc
         prize = driver.find_element('xpath', xRef[uxrKey]).text
    except:
        # pass # you'll just be repeating whatever you got in the previous loop for prize
        # [also, if this happens in the first loop, an error will be raised at lst.append([prize])]

        prize = None # 'MISSING' # '' #
################ REST OF CODE #############
```

---

##### 2. Limitations of Scraping with bs4+requests

I don't know what `et` and `ureq` are, but response from `requests.get` can be parsed without them; although [afaik] bs4 doesn't have any XPath support, css selectors can be used with [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) .

```py
      price = soup.select('.ProductHero__content .ProductPricing>span') # for Ulta
```

```py
      price = soup.select('p[data-comp~="Price"] span>b') # for Sephora
```

Although that's [enough for Sephora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAdGC.png), there's another issue - **the price in Ulta pages are [loaded with js](http://theautomatic.net/2019/01/19/scraping-data-from-javascript-webpage-python/)** so the parent of the price `span` [**is empty**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FDwL.png).

---

##### 3. [Suggested Solution] Extracting from JSON inside `script` Tags

For both sites, product data [can be found inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anOkH.png) `script` tags, so this function can be used to extract price from either site:

```py
# import json

############ LONGER  VERSION ##########
def getPrice_fromScript(scriptTag):
    try:
        s, sj = scriptTag.get_text(), json.loads(scriptTag.get_text())
        while s:
            sPair = s.split('"@type"', 1)[1].split(':', 1)[1].split(',', 1)
            t, s = sPair[0].strip(), sPair[1]
            try: 
                if t == '"Product"': return sj['offers']['price'] # Ulta
                elif t == '"Organization"': return sj['offers'][0]['price'] # Sephora
                # elif.... # can add more options
                # else.... # can add a default
            except: continue
    except: return None
#######################################

############ SHORTER VERSION ##########
def getPrice_fromScript(scriptTag):
    try:
        sj = json.loads(scriptTag.get_text())
        try: return sj['offers']['price'] # Ulta
        except: pass
        try: return sj['offers'][0]['price'] # Sephora
        except: pass 
        # try...except: pass # can try more options
    except: return None
#######################################
```

and you can use it with your BeautifulSoup code:

```py
# from requests_html import HTMLSession # IF you use instead of requests

# def getPrice_fromScript....

for i in range(len(df)):
    response = requests.get(df['product_url'].iloc[i]) # takes too long [for me]
    # response = HTMLSession().get(df['product_url'].iloc[i]) # is faster [for me]

    ## error handing, just in case ##
    if response.status_code != 200:
        errorMsg = f'Failed to scrape [{response.status_code} {response.reason}] - '
        print(errorMsg, df['product_url'].iloc[i])
        continue # skip to next loop/url

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    pList = [p.strip() for p in [
        getPrice_fromScript(s) for s in soup.select('script[type="application/ld+json"]')[:5] # [1:2]
    ] if p and p.strip()]

    if pList: df['price'].iloc[i] = pList[0]
```

(The price should be in the second `script` tag with `type="application/ld+json"`, but this is searching the first 5 just in case....)

---

<sub>**Note:** `requests.get` was being very slow when I was testing these codes, especially for Sephora, so I ended up using [`HTMLSession().get`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#tutorial-usage) instead.</sub>